# Give fix bandwidth to all ip address for internet, but exclude local apache server

Tags: web-server, internet, apache-httpd, jessie-lite, iptables

I have installed chilli, apache2, hostapd in raspberry pi. User can connect hostspot created by hostapd. Captive portal will open asking id password(because of chilli). Once user sign in, user redirect to the ip(say 10.10.10.10) of raspberry pi,which open local webpages stored in apache server which contains mp4 files to play. and in background user can access internet routed from ethernet to wifi hostspot.

Everything works fine. :)

Now i want to give fix bandwidth (say 128kbps(16KB/s)) to all user so that, they can use all messaging app(whatsapp,hangout,facebook massanger.) which use low traffic, and will not use steaming apps like youtube, torrent, google play update etc.

Besides local server(say ip 10.10.10.10) which contain movies in raspberry pi itself can be accessed friction free without any bandwidth restrictions by users.(exception of traffic control).

How to accomplish this. Please suggest software or packages.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `iproute2` and `iptables` packages which you probably already have. You will need to *mark* traffic from different users using `iptables`, then use those marks to apply rate limits using `tc`. In simple cases, `tc` filters can be used to sort packets without the help of `iptables`. Since you want to limit the Internet traffic of each user individually, you will need as many traffic classes as you have users (plus the unlimited local traffic class).

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/advanced_traffic_control) is a nice tutorial explaining how to configure traffic control in Linux.

Comment: Find the below answer, it works the system without coova-chilli(replaced it with isc-dhcp-server). I mean all local data(10.10.10.10 server) will be accessed with 10mbit bandwidth and all other site will be accessed with 160kbit. But with coova chilli same script doesn't work. Is that any way to find why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Install  `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install iproute2`

> Creat file `nano /root/tc.sh`. and Enter following commands:

```
tc qdisc del dev wlan0 root

tc qdisc add dev wlan0 root handle 1: htb default 30
tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 12mbit burst 15k


tc class add dev wlan0  parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 11mbit burst 15k
tc class add dev wlan0  parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 160kbit ceil 160kbit burst 15k

tc qdisc add dev wlan0 parent 1:10 handle 10: sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev wlan0 parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10

tc filter add dev wlan0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip src 10.10.10.10/32 match ip sport 80 0xffff flowid 1:10

echo -e 'qdisq:\n'
tc qdisc show dev wlan0

echo -e '\nclass:\n'  
tc class show dev wlan0

echo -e '\nfilter:\n'
tc filter show dev wlan0
```

run it on boot by placing `sh /root/tc.sh` before `exit0` in `nano /etc/rc.local`

> all details of above script will be find [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/advanced_traffic_control) [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/) and [here](https://www.linux.com/blog/tc-show-manipulate-traffic-control-settings)

Done.